# MDI Child Form Load

Tags: winforms, mdichild, mdiparent

Loading multiple child forms from a loop into a MDI parent form. They are displayed one at a time. I would like to display all the created forms at once. I tried only using the .Show() method after they are all created, but they still only display one at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps layouting your children forms using the [MdiLayout Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.mdilayout.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, will try it and let you know

Comment: It still seems to draw the child forms one at a time as there is processing that takes place in each one

Comment: You for sure need to show your forms. Perhaps showing them in a loop after they all have been instantiated. It is hard to say without knowing exactly the ultimate objective and what you need to achieve that requires such behaviour. =)

Comment: I have a MDI parent form that loads child forms containing gauges that load. Each gauge requires a connection to a seperate database with some data processing to populate the gauge data.

I have tried to create them first. Then Show() them afterwards, but they still load one at  time.